# Does terraform apply also refresh the state against what is already deployed?

Tags: terraform

Suppose I run `terraform apply` without the `refresh` flag and with no plan mentioned.

Will terraform refresh the state of what I have defined as IaC against the state of what is already deployed? Or will it only look at my current state file and compare that with what I updated as IaC.

The documentation does not mention the default refresh behavior of terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform will automatically refresh the state before running a command that would rely on it (such as `plan`, `apply`, `destroy`).

You can see this yourself by looking at the output from running these commands:

```
$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.aws_region.current: Refreshing state...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.
```

Answer (score 2):

terraform apply will check for new state always. Any terraform action will always first refresh the state by default. Ideally, you should always do a `terraform plan -out <planName>.plan` and then apply this plan on the environment using `terraform apply <planName>.plan`. This ensures consistency and you exactly know what is going to happen in the environment. 
In cases where the plan is old and there have been changes to the environment meanwhile, terraform will detect that and will give you an error - forcing you to plan and apply again.